# java command line Class IllegalAcessError

Tags: java, command-line, terminal

Running a java Class that calls two other classes.
I successfully compiled the .java files into .class files and they are put in the  same folder as the .java files. Running java main.java gives me:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError:
It tells me that in my main I am getting an error attempting to use a static variable from a new otherClass OtherClass(); that I called in main.
So attempting otherClass.variable throws the error-> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError:

Please help? Why is this happening and what is the fix

I have finally figured out that having .class and .java files in the same folder allows you to run the command line program. But after that I ran into this error and I am not sure why I cannot access the other classes variable.

```
//this is where I call the new class
static OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass();


//this is where the error occurs
System.out.println("Your current location is (" + (otherClass.variable - 1) + "," + (otherClass.variable - 1) + ")");
```

I expects to be able to access the variable and all other variables in the class.

Comment: We need to see a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to understand what is going on here; i.e. actual compilable and runnable code *and* the stacktrace that you get when you run the code.

Comment: For what it is worth, I suspect that the real problem is that the code has not been built correctly; i.e. you have changed and recompiled a class without recompiling the other classes that depend on it.  It can easily happen when you use `javac` directly rather than using a build tool (Ant, Maven, Gradle) or an IDE to build your code.

Answer (score 0):

***o***therClass is an instance of ***O***therClass. If *variable* is static, then it should be accessed by the class, *OtherClass*, and not the instance,  *otherClass*.

Comment: I think I figured out. Making the variable public allows the main class to access those variables while running the command line app.